# Use Fluid as templating engine in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fluid

I'd like to know how to use Fluid (Neos, Flow3) as templating engine in Symfony.

I don't have any idea how to implement it. I knew a guy who implemented it and it worked properly.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: https://github.com/mia3/FluidBundle

Comment: What about learning Twig ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [FluidBundle](https://github.com/mia3/FluidBundle).

Hope this help